# Regular expression for optional character in between the numerals

Tags: swift, regex, regex-group, nsregularexpression

I need to validate a string that contains underscore(_) in between the numbers. Underscore character is an optional.
Only *condition is, it should be between the numbers*.

```
Valid     => 123
Valid     => 1_23
Valid     => 123_4567_89_312_575

Not valid => 123_
Not valid => _123
Not valid => 123__12   (Two consecutive underscore characters)
Not valid => _         (Number is mandatory)
Not valid => abc       (only numbers and _ should be present)
```

I have tried this regular expression

```
([0-9]+_*[0-9]+)*
```

It failed. Any idea why ?

PS:
Going to implement this in swift language.
Core logic: Underscore character is used like a separator for numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `([0-9]+_*[0-9]+)*` pattern matches 0+ repetitions of 1+ digits, 0+ underscores and then 1+ digits. So, it can match `12`, `3_______4`, `2345`, and an empty string. Depending on what method you are using it in, it may match partial, or the whole string.

You may use

```
^[0-9]+(?:_[0-9]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yade2F/1)

If you use the pattern inside `NSPredicate` with `MATCHES`, the `^` and `$` anchors are not necessary as in that case the whole string should match the pattern.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing grouping

  - `_` - an underscore
  - `[0-9]+` - 1+ digits
- `)*` - repeats the pattern sequence 0 or more times
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 3):

Simple it should be **either**:

`^[0-9]+(_[0-9]+)*$`  or

`^\d+(_\d+)*$` ,

both of which means start with any number(`<number>`) then have any(**zero or more**) number of combinations of pattern(`_<number>`) underscore and number.

**OR vice-versa,**

`([0-9]+_)*[0-9]+` or

`(\d+_)*\d+` ,

both of which means start with any(**zero or more**) number of combinations of pattern(`<number>_`) number and underscore; and then have any number(`<number>`).

Comment: @curiousManish: Now you copied my answer

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish: now its cover all cases

Comment: Sorry @JogendarChoudhary I don't think so, both of them have same meaning,just added another approach to achieve this.
And btw i didn't copied you answer ("^[0-9]+(_*[0-9]+)*$") which you later realized was incorrect and u updated your answer to match  with mine.
Anyway happy days, enjoy dude !

Answer (score 2):

You may use this expression:

```
^\d+(_\d+)*$
```

[image]

Comment: oh u very smartly edited and matched with mine regex, finally !

Comment: Please check, this is not yours

Comment: oh man you just deleted your 1st answer and posted one which is another form of mine regex, which also says start with number and then have any combination of (_<number>)*.
Anyway, whatever it is not sure what you want to achieve by again and again deleting and changing your answers, it's good that finally you realized that your initial answer("^[0-9]+(_*[0-9]+)*$";) was incorrect.

Comment: Yes man, That time I didn't read question bottom line "PS: Two consecutive underscore character is invalid. Going to implement this in swift language." that's why. Thank you